# Refactoring from classes to functions - ways to enhance in functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-hooks

I am trying to rewrite class components to functions.

Often, I have an enhanced component as class property:

```
class Grid extends Component {

  tableCell = params => (
     <TableCell paging={this.props.paging} {...params} />
  )

  render() {
    return <Table tableCell={this.tableCell} />
  }
}
```

When writing function, I have to move the enhancing outside of function body, or it will get re-mounted on each render.

```
const tableCell = params => <TableCell {...params} />

function Grid(props) {
  return <Table tableCell={tableCell} />
}
```

Table is an external Component (devexpressGrid), but I suppose it does something like this:

```
function Table(props) {
  const TableCell = props.tableCell
  return <TableCell param1={true} param2={true} />
}
```

Is there a way, to still pass a prop from Grid to tableCell? This prop is not coming from any redux store, it is given when rendering Grid, like this:

```
return <Grid paging="infinite-scroll" />
```

You can see the differences here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/w2y76w53ww?fontsize=14

Comment: You could do `<Table tableCell={params => <TableCell paging={paging} {...params} />} />`

Comment: *it will get re-mounted on each render* - what did make you think so? TableCell will be rerendered on each render, not remounted. If it's remounted, the problem is in Table and should be addressed accordingly.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/w2y76w53ww?fontsize=14 please try to mount App & AppClass and check the console. What am I doing wrong? And how to address the problem in Table? @estus

Comment: @JSkr Please, update the question with Table source code. It's relevant, the question should be understandable without navigating to external links, they may become dead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Table` treats `tableCell` function as a component. If there's new function, the hierarchy is remounted. And new function is supposed to be created in order to use `props` from `Grid`, it cannot work the same way as it does in class component because there's no `this.prop` that could be accessed as a property during component lifespan.

This is a common problem. React Router solves it by having separate [`component` and `render` props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/route-props). Accidentally providing newly created function as `component` will result in very same problem, a component will be remounted on each render.

`tableCell` should be treated as regular function rather than a component. As another answer mentions, `tableCell` is called [render prop](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

`Table` component should be:

```
function Table(props) {
  return props.tableCell({param1: true, param2: true});
}
```

Accidentally providing a component as render prop may result in error. It's a good practice to follow naming convention and call a prop the way its purpose is clear, e.g. `renderCell` for render prop and `Cell` or `cellComponent` for a component.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new function inline and give it directly to the `tableCell` prop.

```
function Grid(props) {
  return (
    <Table tableCell={params => <TableCell paging={paging} {...params} />} />
  )
}
```

If you don't want to create a new function every render, you can use the [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) hook.

```
function Grid(props) {
  const tableCell = useCallback(
    params => <TableCell paging={paging} {...params} />,
    [paging]
  );

  return <Table tableCell={tableCell} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the renderProps pattern here (I think its still OK to use it - but you probably could be even cooler and look at replacing it with Hooks)

```
function Table(props) {
  return (
    <div>
     {props.render(props)}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Implementation:

```
function Grid(props) {
  return (
    <Table render={(props) => <TableCell {...props} />} />
  )
}
```

So your Table can render any component and pass it all or some of the props required. IMHO it makes a Table very flexible.